# How to configure the web samples into IIS Express 7.5 server using c#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Need to deploy the web samples from IIS Express 7.5 server. I have some web samples in different platforms (Asp.NET,Asp.Net MVC, Silverlight) projects. i have created a startup exe to run the sample browser.

If IIS Express 7.5 has been installed in the machine, then include the entries in an xml file . with reference to xml file web samples will run using IIS Express 7.5. If the machine has IIS express 7.5 installed means the web samples has been run from the IIS Express 7.5, else it has been run from the default ASP.Net web development server.

How to deploy the web samples into IIS Express 7.5 server using c#?

can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need to write any code to do this.

Comment: [What have your tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: i have created a new web project and right click on my project-> clicked Use IIS Express and set SSL = True. Execute this project and it ran in IIS Express server. But when i unload the project and run the project using the link say http://localhost:13356. it did not run

Comment: I dont wanna do this by manually. If IIS Express installed in the machine, the project will run using IIS Express server. Already i have configured all my samples to run in IIS using C#. it is fine. Now i implement the same for IIS Express. can you please help

Answer (score 1):

You would have to make modifications in machine.config to set the defaults. While working in Visual Studio, the easiest way is to right click on your web project, go to Properties -> Use Local IIS Server -> select Use IIS Express.